# C print only sign of integers

Tags: c, printing, sign

I was wondering if (and how) one can print only the sign of an array entry. For example I'd have something like

```
{1, -1, -1, 1}
```

and I would like the output to look something like

```
+ - - +
```

I'm pretty new to C and the only solution I can come up with is some sort of `if (... < 0)` contdition that results in either a `+` or `-` char. But that seems quite unhandy.

This is merely meant to pretty up large "patterns" I am drawing with `+1` and `-1`. I'd really be glad if someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. This is the approach I would use. While bitwise operations would also work, something is to be said for readability.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int numbers[4] = {1, -1, -1, -1};

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0])); i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", (numbers[i] < 0 ? "-" : "+"));
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Or you can build a string with `sprintf()` / `snprintf()`; not sure if you want to output it or use it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, with some tweaks this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Awesome, no problem, glad I could help! :)

Comment: In a 1k x 1k array it really looks a lot better without the '1's

Comment: Absolutely. You could even color the `-`'s red and the `+`'s green if that fits your output format (for example, ANSI colors on the shell, or HTML colors on the web).

Answer (score 3):

The way you have mentioned is effective for this purpose. If you want to do same thing by some other way, you can use ternary operator as:

```
a[i] < 0 ? printf("-"): printf("+");
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about this operator.

Comment: My pleasure. Don't forget to approve the answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
[this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

The flag `+` forces the output to show the sign of a number

Comment: But you can't use it without printing the number as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it be possible to force the sign and then 'cut' the length of the printed string, so as only the sign would be printed?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int num [4] = {1, -1, -1, 1);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
        if (num [i] < 0) {
            printf ("-");
         }
         else
            printf ("+");
    }
    return 0;
}
```